# Finding the filename of the embedded XLSX file when editing a chart via DOCX4J

Tags: charts, docx4j

I have a Word document (docx) with at least 8 charts. Each of these charts needs to be updated automatically. I'm able to change the data in the document, but still need to find a way of editing the embedded xlsx file. How can I find for each of the charts the corresponding filename of the embedded file ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, but I don't know if this is waterproof...

```
private void findEmbeddedXlsx(Chart chart) {
    RelationshipsPart rp = chart.getRelationshipsPart();
    for ( Relationship r : rp.getRelationships().getRelationship() ) {
       if (r.getType().equals(Namespaces.EMBEDDED_PKG)) {
           try {
               //tgt is the filename of the embedded file
               String tgt = r.getTarget();
               //... whatever you need to do with the embedded file
           } catch (Docx4JException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           } 
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps anyone that needs to get hold of this... Remarks on this are more than welcome !